# How do I translate menu link URIs?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Is there a way to translate a menu link URI?

When I change it in one language (e.g. http://www.example.**com**), it is also changed in the other language, where I want a different domain (e.g. http://www.example.**de**).

Link title and description is working as expected.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to translate the menu uri itself. If you want different menu links per language you need to create a unique menu per language, and use block visibility settings to limit each menu block to its respective language.

See this Drupal 8 multilingual hack for a step by step guide: [build unique menus per languages](http://www.drupal8multilingual.org/features-used-hacks/menu-language)

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar requirement. The best solution I found for myself on Drupal 8.5.x was [Translatable menu link uri](https://www.drupal.org/project/translatable_menu_link_uri) module. You just need to install and follow the steps mentioned in the module description.

Answer (score 2):

Change the menu-link URL-alias as per the required language

for e.g.

I wanna products page URL in French
=> /produits
and I wanna products page URL in Netherlands
=> /producten

than first create a menu and place the menu item in it
=> main menu
- products (menu item)
/node/1 (menu link)
URL-alias:-
go to the URL alias and add the alias for French language
=>  select the language French
=> IN System path "/node/1"
=> In Alias path "produits"
Like wise for the Netherlands site
=>  select the language Dutch
=> IN System path "/node/1"
=> In Alias path "/producten"

and the title of the link are being translatable from menus itself only

Note:- Enable this settings located at Configuration => "Content language and translation" enable the menu custom menu link,content,custom block and tick all the all their check boxes specially URL-alias in content.and don't forget to enable the Drupal 8 multilingual modules.

Comment: Thanks, this might work. But it seems not very handy for the editor to "translate" menu links via URL alias. Different menus per language is currently the way to go.

Comment: And this approach does only work for internal links, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to have language-specific external links. I created a module that addresses this issue. https://github.com/bbenjamin/Drupal-8---Multilingual-Menu-Links 
With this module, if users are translating a menu item, they are given the option of adding a language specific external link. If they choose this option, the default Name and Link fields are hidden, and replaced with language-specific fields.

Answer (score 1):

A quite small module we used is [Menu Multilingual](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_multilingual):

> The Menu Multilingual module provides multilingual features for menu blocks, to filter out menu items that do not have translated labels or link to untranslated content.

You have to create a menu link for each language and on the configuration for the menu block you should activate both options:

[image]